# simple ipfw configuration with nat on FreeBSD with two nick and dhcp

Tags: freebsd, nat, ipfw

anyone can write down a simple ipfw configuration with nat and two nick with dhcp ?
This is my configuration:

- ue0 --> dhcpd server and lan
- ue1 --> dhclient and internet with other router

And these are my other configuraiton that don't work.

```
# ifconfig 
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        groups: lo
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
ue0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=80009<RXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,LINKSTATE>
        ether xxxxxxxxxxf:7f
        inet 192.168.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
ipfw0: flags=8800<SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 65536
        groups: ipfw
ue1: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        ether xxxxxxxx:ad
        inet 172.20.10.2 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 172.20.10.15
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>



/etc/ipfw.conf
ipfw -q -f flush
c="ipfw"
cmd="ipfw -q add"
cmdnat="ipfw -q nat"
pif="ue1"       # INTERFACCIA INTERNET
lan="ue0"       # INTERFACCIA LAN
$c disable one_pass
$cmd 00005 allow all from any to any via $lan
$cmd 00010 allow all from any to any via lo0
$cmd 00101 check-state
$cmd 00110 allow tcp from any to 8.8.8.8 53 out via $pif setup keep-state
$cmd 00111 allow udp from any to 8.8.8.8 53 out via $pif keep-state
$cmd 00120 allow log udp from any to any 67 out via $pif keep-state
$cmd 00200 allow tcp from any to any 80 out via $pif setup keep-state
$cmd 00220 allow tcp from any to any 443 out via $pif setup keep-state
$cmd 00250 allow icmp from any to any out via $pif keep-state
$cmd 00260 allow udp from any to any 123 out via $pif keep-state
# $cmdnat 1 config if $pif same_ports unreg_only reset
# $cmdnat 1 config if $pif same_ports 
ipfw nat 123 config ip 172.20.10.2
# $cmd 105 nat 10 ip from any to any in via $pif
# $cmd 500 nat 1  ip from any to any out via $pif keep-state
# $cmd 10000 nat 1 ip4 from any to any out xmit
$cmd 00299 deny log all from any to any out via $pif




/etc/rc.conf
sshd_enable="NO"
usbmuxd_enable="YES"
sendmail_enable="NONE"
sendmail_submit_enable="NO"
sendmail_outbound_enable="NO"
sendmail_msp_queue_enable="NO"
growfs_enable="YES"
netif_enable="YES"
ifconfig_ue1="SYNCDHCP"
ifconfig_ue0="inet 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0"
dhcpd_enable="YES"     
dhcpd_flags="ue0"      
ntpdate_enable="YES"
mixer_enable="NO"
ntpd_enable="YES"
firewall_enable="YES"
# firewall_type="simple"
gateway_enable="YES"
firewall_nat_enable="YES"
firewall_script="/etc/ipfw.rules"
firewall_logging="YES"
firewall_logif="YES"
```

Comment: Not sure what rules you need for DHCP, the firewall may not even see them. But your `nat config` should use `if ue1` as the IP address is dynamic. And you are currently missing the `nat` rule. See `/etc/rc.firewall` for examples.

Comment: About the nat I have tried all the rulles in bottom of /etc/ipfw.rules file. That now are commented.

Comment: `ipfw` can support a large number of separate NAT instances. You need to use the same number in your config and rule statements. You have configured number 123, and set up rules for numbers 1 and 10.

Comment: @RichardSmith hi again, I have tried [this](https://sirtoffski.github.io/docs/freebsd-ipfw/) but does not work. The strange thing is the if I do **ipfw nat show config** it gave me the old config. It seems that the script from [here](https://sirtoffski.github.io/docs/freebsd-ipfw/) does not change anything.  Please looks [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SXcsJs3wg5/)

Comment: It probably doesn't matter that the old config is present. I suspect `flush` removes the rules but does not remove the config.